# C# 2008 Express Edition Increasing the font size

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have just installed C# 2008 Express Edition 2008 and started writing code. My mom being too concerned about the time I spend programming is worried about the font size :-). Is there anyway, that I can increase the size of font so that I can do programming in a larger font size in C# 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Main menu,

Tools, Options, Environment: Fonts and Colors

Comment: Actually, it's kind of a slow day today.